# How to deselect a checkbox field with a trigger?

Tags: trigger, checkbox

can someone help me out? I have a checkbox field and when the user inserts a file this field is 'true' through a trigger, how can I make it 'false' if the user deletes the files? I really appreciate anyone who can help.
My first attempt was to create a flow that analyzed if the files existed, but it doesn't seem possible to do that anymore...

```
trigger HasAttachment on ContentDocumentLink (after insert) {
String tempParentId;
    Set<Id> setParentId = new Set<Id>();
    List<Ensaios_de_DM__c> Ensaiolst = new List<Ensaios_de_DM__c>();
    
 for (ContentDocumentLink cdl : trigger.new ) {
            tempParentId = cdl.LinkedEntityId;
     
            if (tempParentId.left(3) =='a1f') {
                System.debug('Debug : found a1f');
                System.debug('Debug : content document id ' + cdl.ContentDocumentId );
                setParentId.add(cdl.LinkedEntityId);
            }
        }
    Ensaiolst = [select Id , Tem_Anexo__c from Ensaios_de_DM__c where Id IN :setParentId];
     
     For(Ensaios_de_DM__c e : Ensaiolst)
     {
        e.Tem_Anexo__c = true;
     }

     update Ensaiolst;
}
```

Comment: As you mentioned, you need to set the flag as 'false' if the user deletes the file. So, I believe if you add 'after delete' event in your trigger and add the logic for making the flag as false in 'after delete' event this might work.

Comment: I'm new to salesforce, what would that logic look like? I barely understand this code I posted lol @tandonprateek

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code little bit, used your trigger and a class to differentiate the logic between the trigger events.

**HasAttachment.trigger**

```
    trigger HasAttachment on ContentDocumentLink (after insert, before delete) {

    ContentDocumentLinkTriggerHelper handler = new ContentDocumentLinkTriggerHelper();
        if(Trigger.isDelete && Trigger.isBefore){
            handler.OnBeforeDelete(Trigger.oldMap);
        }
    
    if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter){
            handler.OnAfterInsert(Trigger.newMap);
        }


}
```

**ContentDocumentLinkTriggerHelper.cls**

```
public class ContentDocumentLinkTriggerHelper {
    public void onAfterInsert(Map<ID, ContentDocumentLink> newContentDocumentLinkMap){
        String tempParentId;
            Set<Id> setParentId = new Set<Id>();
            List<Ensaios_de_DM__c> ensaiolst = new List<Ensaios_de_DM__c>();
    
        for (ContentDocumentLink cdl : newContentDocumentLinkMap.values() ) {
                    tempParentId = cdl.LinkedEntityId;
     
                    if (tempParentId.left(3) =='a1f') {
                        System.debug('Debug : found a1f');
                        System.debug('Debug : content document id ' + cdl.ContentDocumentId );
                        setParentId.add(cdl.LinkedEntityId);
                    }
            }
            ensaiolst = [select Id , Tem_Anexo__c from Ensaios_de_DM__c where Id IN :setParentId];
     
            For(Ensaios_de_DM__c e : ensaiolst){
                e.Tem_Anexo__c = true;
            }

            update Ensaiolst;
    }

    public void onBeforeDelete(Map<ID, ContentDocumentLink> oldContentDocumentLinkMap){
        String tempParentId;
            Set<Id> setParentId = new Set<Id>();
        List<Ensaios_de_DM__c> ensaiolst = new List<Ensaios_de_DM__c>();
    
        for (ContentDocumentLink cdl : oldContentDocumentLinkMap.values() ) {
            tempParentId = cdl.LinkedEntityId;

                    if (tempParentId.left(3) =='a1f') {
                        System.debug('Debug : found a1f');
                        System.debug('Debug : content document id ' + cdl.ContentDocumentId );
                        setParentId.add(cdl.LinkedEntityId);
                    }
            }
            ensaiolst = [select Id , Tem_Anexo__c from Ensaios_de_DM__c where Id IN :setParentId];
     
            For(Ensaios_de_DM__c e : ensaiolst){
                e.Tem_Anexo__c = false;
            }

            update Ensaiolst;
    }
}
```

I have not tested this code, but might give you some idea.